# Alternative to SurfaceView?

Tags: android, view, surfaceview

I am making a custom ProgressBar which has a bitmap that just rotates. if I use the View.invalidate the FPS will stutter; the deltaTime will go up 40+ many times. The logic and render is almost instantaneous but the invalidate call makes it slow. So I am trying the SurfaceView, problem is I have had problems earlier assemble SurfaceViews with other Views and I would like not to use it. Are there any alternative to SurfaceView and View.invalidate or am I stuck with them?

**EDIT:**

To clarify some more, I am making a custom **View** that is an **intermediate** ProgressBar. So the View is the ProgressBar. I am also not downloading anything now, I am only trying to get max FPS for my View. Some code:

```
MyProgressBar extends View implements Runnable
```

And the run()

```
calculateNewRotation();
invalidate();
post(this);
```

Where calculateNewRotation()

```
long now = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
int deltaTime = (int) (now - mLastRender);
mLastRender = now;
mSpinRotation += deltaTime * SPIN_SPEED_PER_MILLISECOND_CLOCKWISE;
```

Post(this) refer to MyProgressBar and it will loop for all eternity until I say otherwise.

In my onDraw()

```
mCamera.save();
mCamera.rotateZ(mSpinRotation);
mCamera.getMatrix(mMatrix);
mCamera.restore();

mMatrix.preTranslate(-mTranslatePivotX, -mTranslatePivotY);
mMatrix.postTranslate(mTranslatePivotX + mCenterX, mTranslatePivotY + mCenterY);

canvas.drawBitmap(mSpinBitmap, mMatrix, mSpinBitmapPaint);
```

Time for calculateNewRotation() = 1 ms.

Time for onDraw() = 1 ms.

Problem is the overall time is often above 40 ms. My solution is to then use a SurfaceView, but I do not like the idea to have a View with it's surface drawn with transparent pixels so the underlying surface will be shown instead. What I am looking for is a View that I may get the canvas whenever I want, preferably every 16 ms to get 60 FPS. Now, is there such a View?

Comment: Stuck with them? They are absolutely fine. It is the way you are using them.

Comment: @Doomsknight so why am I getting FPS stutter from invalidate? My logic/render is almost instantaneous.

Comment: Unless Im mistaken, invalidate causes the UI thread to update at its next convienience. This does not mean instantly. Options are a separate thread that updates it. Take a look at the Lunar landing example.

Comment: @Doomsknight Right, so I need to use the SurfaceView then? Problem I had was that if it was used with say a HorizontalScrollView (facebook menu implementation) and a fragment with a viewpager that held many SurfaceViews, if you scrolled the ViewPager to index 1 and then clicked the facebook menu the SurefaceView on index 0 would overlap the facebook menu and if I hid the ViewPager it would be a nice black box covering it all..

Comment: as barconr mentions the best idea would be async task. Which is effectively a wrapper around the thread class. I think a surfaceview would be overkill for what you want. Async classes usually handle progress bars. They should be fine for a custom one. Seeing some code would help.

Comment: @Doomsknight Please read my edited text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did in the end was when I have drawn the image I update the rotation value by 1. On fast and slow phones it will look smooth, but the speed will be different. On a fast phone it might draw 60 frames per second which is 60 degrees a second, when a slow phone with 10 frames per second will make the spin go 10 degrees a second. So in the end it is all about if I want them to rotate at the same speed or make it look good, I choose the latter one.

**EDIT**

I suppose I could put in a max frames per second so fast phones will be throttled and thus making the gap between fast and small phones smaller.

Answer (score 1):

Are you doing a long operation (typically the reason for needing a progress bar) on the UI thread? Your UI thread should be updating the progress bar while another thread or an async task handles the long operation.

Comment: While I test my custom implementation I do not do any work at all, I just have my progress bar spinning and spinning with stutters.

Comment: Calculate the delta time based on your draw method. Invalidate() may not actually redraw the screen so it make no sense to calculate the delta time in the other method/thread. Calculating the delta time in onDraw() will ensure it has the correct value since the last draw. Try that and see if your time improves.

Comment: Try call postInvalidate() instead of invalidate(), improvement?

Comment: No improvement, it still stutters.. Guess I have to look through the code a third time.

Comment: Post the entire contents of run() and  post() perhaps?